# re-write ifelse to switch

Tags: javascript, if-statement, switch-statement, indexof

How would I go about re-writing this `ifelse` to a `switch`?

```
var d = document,
    a = 'foo',
    b = 'bar',
    c = 'foobar';

if (d.URL.indexOf(a) != -1 || d.URL.indexOf(b) != -1)
{

    // do this

}
elseif(d.URL.indexOf(c) != -1)
{

    // do something else

}
```

it goes on for about 10 more `ifelse` which is why i'd prefer to change it to `switch`

I've searched for answers and found nothing so tried this:

```
function io(i)
{
    d.URL.indexOf(i) != -1;
}

switch (io())
{
case a:
case b:
    // do this
    break;
case c:
    // do this
    break;
}
```

and a few variations of the same thing but I'm very much a JS novice and so knew I was probably wrong (which I was).

Comment: a) Have you tried [Google](http://www.google.com/search?q=javascript+switch+statement) to find out about the syntax of a switch statement? b) format your code examples!

Comment: Yes of course, (extra :) ma bad.

Comment: Sorry for all the ninja edits, but my answer should be what you need now.

Answer (score 1):

I think the best thing to do here would be to actually create an array of objects with their functions, then you would just cycle through that array using [`every`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every). Here's some demonstration code using your above example:

```
var choices = [
  {
    value: foo,
    fn: function () { // do this }
  },
  {
    value: 'foobar',
    fn: function () { // do something else }
  }
];
choices.every( function( choice ) {
  if ( document.URL.indexOf( choice.value ) !== -1 ) {
    choice.fn();
    return false;
  } else return true;
});
```

If you have functions you know will be used multiple times, you just create them outside of the array and assign them to the `fn` key of multiple objects. By using `return true` when you don't encounter it, it'll keep moving through the array, then when it hits one where it's true, it'll `return false` and end the every function.